# $ \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n^3(n^3+1)}. $

Tags: sequences-and-series

The series is:
$$
\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n^3(n^3+1)}.
$$
I tried splitting the whole thing into simple fractions but I don't seem to get anywhere.

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by "solve"? Do you want to find the closed form of the series? Or do you want to prove that the series is convergent?

Comment: I want to find the sum of the series. I can compute a floating point value myself with a computer, but I just want to find the exact value.

Comment: The sum is $\zeta(3) - 1 - \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n^3+1}$. I do not think that you can get anything much better.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac1{n^3(n^3+1)}
&=\sum_{n=2}^\infty\left(\frac1{n^3}-\frac1{n^3+1}\right)\\
&=\sum_{n=2}^\infty\left(\frac1{n^3}-\frac1{n^3(1+1/n^3)}\right)\\
&=\sum_{n=2}^\infty\left(\frac1{n^3}-\frac1{n^3}\left(1-\frac1{n^3}+\frac1{n^6}-\dots\right)\right)\\
&=\sum_{n=2}^\infty\left(\frac1{n^6}-\frac1{n^9}+\frac1{n^{12}}-\dots\right)\\
&=\sum_{n=2}^\infty(-1)^n(\zeta(3n)-1)\\
&\stackrel.=0.01555356082097039944\tag{22 terms}
\end{align}
$$
**Added Note:** Since $\zeta(3n)-1\sim1/8^n$, each term in the sum gives over $0.9$ digits.

Answer (score 4):

*Hint*: Obsereve that 
$$\frac1{n^3(n^3+1)}=\frac1{n^3}-\frac1{n^3+1}$$
And remember that $\zeta(s)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^s}$.

Comment: How to calculate $\sum\frac{1}{n^3+1}$? It is not equal to $\sum \frac{1}{(n+1)^3}$.

Comment: No, it is not. This simpliefies a little, but you probably can't get any better than that.

Answer (score 3):

$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n^3(n^3+1)} = \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n^3}+\frac{n-2}{3 (n^2-n+1)}-\frac{1}{3 (n+1)} = \\
\zeta{(3)} -1 + \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{n-2}{3 (n^2-n+1)}-\frac{1}{3 (n+1)} = \\
\zeta{(3)}-1  -\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^3+1} \approx \\
0.015553560820970399435132949324595238582753593120862693333639...$$

Comment: use Euler Maclaurin summation formula http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_Maclaurin