# Sum the infinite series of $\frac{1}{r^3+1}$

Tags: real-analysis, summation

Is there a definite value for the sum:

$S=\displaystyle\sum_{r=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{r^3+1}$

And if so, how would I arrive at finding this sum?

I have tried reducing the above into partial fractions, however I can't seem to arrive at any definitive answer (preferably in terms of elementary function).

Comment: Compare with this question: (not a duplicate, but connected) http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/331850/sum-n-2-infty-frac1n3n31/331858#331858

Comment: Mathematica gives no closed form result. This doesnt mean there is no closed form, however it means that there probably is none. Numerically, we get 0.6865033423...

Comment: @CBenni: WolframAlpha for Sum[1/(r^3+1),{r,1,Infinity}] extresses it in terms of the digamma function. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function

Comment: @NickKidman: Yes, but that is not a closed form, as the digamma function is not a elementary function. Also interesting to see that Wolfram|Alpha gives a completely different result than Mathematica :/

Comment: @Dennis Gulko Thank you for the link, I see how they introduced the Zeta function. However I still would rather have the solution in terms of elementary function.

Comment: @Sy123: they introduced the Zeta function not because they like it - but rather because there *is no* elementary function

Answer (score 7):

Partial fractions gives
$$
\frac1{k^3+1}=\frac13\left(\frac1{k+1}-\frac\alpha{k-\alpha}-\frac\beta{k-\beta}\right)\tag{1}
$$
where $\alpha+\beta=1$ and $\alpha\beta=1$. Set $\alpha=\dfrac{1+i\sqrt3}{2}$ and $\beta=\dfrac{1-i\sqrt3}{2}$.

The [digamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function) is
$$
\psi(z+1)=-\gamma+\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(\frac1k-\frac1{k+z}\right)\tag{2}
$$
where $\gamma$ is the [Euler-Mascheroni constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant).

So what Wolfram-Alpha is returning is simply
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{k^3+1}
&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac13\left(\frac1{k+1}-\frac\alpha{k-\alpha}-\frac\beta{k-\beta}\right)\\
&=-\frac13\left(-\gamma+\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(\frac1k-\frac1{k+1}\right)\right)\\
&\hphantom{=}+\frac\alpha3\left(-\gamma+\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(\frac1k-\frac1{k-\alpha}\right)\right)\\
&\hphantom{=}+\frac\beta3\left(-\gamma+\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(\frac1k-\frac1{k-\beta}\right)\right)\\
&=\frac\alpha3\psi(1-\alpha)+\frac\beta3\psi(1-\beta)-\frac13(1-\gamma)\tag{3}
\end{align}
$$
Plugging $(3)$ into Mathematica yields $0.686503342338623885964605212187$.

---

Note that $(3)$ and [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/331879) sum to $\zeta(3)-\frac12$. Thus,
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{k^3+1}=\frac12+\sum_{k=1}^\infty(-1)^{k-1}(\zeta(3k)-1)\tag{4}
$$
which as commented in the other answer, converges over $0.9$ digits per term.

Comment: Thank you for the comprehensive solution.